# Proper way of setting up access rights?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a user management system - However I am current finding myself checking the user type on a per router bases.

```
router.get('/admin/settings', (req, res) => {
    if(admin) {
        //Proceed.
    }
}

router.get('/admin/users', (req, res) => {
    if(admin) {
        //Proceed.
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Can't I just set a route like this?

```
router.get('/admin*', (req, res) => {
    if(!admin) {
        res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
}
```

(I have tried and not succeeded, feels like it clashes with other routes)

Also, on a similar note. How Am I supposed to handle denying a user access to a script? Do I send a 404 or 403?

Comment: Huh 404 or 403? Have you even bothered to look up what those codes stand for?

Comment: 404 - Not found, 403 -  Forbidden status. I don't see your point here, if I am denying a post request to a script I figured I would at least send a response back rather than just doing nothing.

Comment: My point is I don't think  you bothered to look at all. Here I'll google that for you. [Status Code Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Hmmm 401 Unauthorized? Nah why would you use that?

Comment: @gforce301 401 Unauthorized is generally used for when the client hasn't authenticated at all. A 403 is designed for cases where the user is known, but doesn't have privilege to the resource. There is some ambiguity because some servers *do* send 404 when a 401 or 403 would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Express middleware function:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(admin) {
    return next();
  }

  // We fail closed
  return res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
});

// This won't get called if the middleware doesn't call next()
router.get('/admin/settings', (req, res) => {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Here, we call `next()` only if the user is an `admin`, which allows the call to continue. Any routes added after this middleware will be protected.

> Also, on a similar note. How Am I supposed to handle denying a user access to a script?

A 403 is the appropriate code here, though a 404 can also be used if you wish to hide the route from unauthorized clients. I would suggest [reading up on what each code is designed for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall give this a try. 

Would using 404 be fine as well? considering is an admin script - wouldn't hiding the fact that it exists in the first place be a good idea?

Comment: A 404 is completely fine to use. If you want to hide the fact that this route exists from un-authenticated users, I would recommend it.